# Generating xml from text file

Tags: xpath, xslt-2.0

I need to generate a well formatted XML structure from the text file, using xslt. I am a newbie to xslt transformation and this looks a bit challenging for me. 
The sample text file is as follows. I need to omit the first portion and map the value in quotes to the output xml file.

```
Directory:    sample/archive
Name:         20130613-T210002.TXT
---------------------------------------------------------------
"11FCK1GR0026" "G190" "FPB - OK Ship Pt" "A" "11" "XX" "02"
"11FCA1GR0034" "G980" "FPB -San Antonio" "A" "11" "XX" "02"
"11FCA1GR0034" "G160" "FPB -San Antonio" "A" "11" "XX" "02"
```

Below is the desired Output xml format:

```
<Account>
    <Action>A</Action> <!-- 3rd element in the row-->
    <org>G190</org> <!-- 2nd element-->
    <code>11FCK1GR002611XX</code> <!--concat(1st element, 4th element, 5th element)-->  
    <FiscalYear>2013</FiscalYear> <!--calculate fiscal year from current date -->
    <Info>
        <Action>A</Action> <!-- 3rd element in the row-->
        <org>G190</org> <!-- 2nd element-->
        <code>11FCK1GR002611XX</code><!--concat(1st element, 4th element, 5th element)-->
        <Fieldlab>Acc1</Fieldlab> <!-- Static value-->
        <FieldVal>11FCK1GR0026 </FieldVal> <!-- if field order is 1, map 1st element -->
        <FieldOrd>1</FieldOrd> <!-- Static value-->
    <Info>
    <Info>
        <Action>A</Action>
        <org>G190</org> 
        <code>11FCK1GR002611XX</code>
        <Fieldlab>Acc2</Fieldlab>
        <FieldVal>11</FieldVal>  <!-- if field order is 2, map 5th element -->
        <FieldOrd>2</FieldOrd>
    <Info>
    <Info>
        <Action>A</Action> <!-- 4th element in the row-->
        <org>G190</org> <!-- 2nd element-->
        <code>11FCK1GR002611XX</code>
        <Fieldlab>Acc3</Fieldlab>
        <FieldVal>xx</FieldVal> <!-- if field order is 3, map 6th element -->
        <FieldOrd>3</FieldOrd>
    <Info>
    <Info>
        <Action>A</Action> <!-- 4th element in the row-->
        <org>G190</org> <!-- 2nd element-->
        <code>11FCK1GR002611XX</code>
        <Fieldlab>Acc4</Fieldlab>
        <FieldVal>02</FieldVal> <!-- if field order is 4, map 7th element -->
        <FieldOrd>4</FieldOrd>
    <Info>
    <Info>
        <Action>A</Action> <!-- 4th element in the row-->
        <org>G190</org> <!-- 2nd element-->
        <code>11FCK1GR002611XX</code>
        <Fieldlab>Acc5</Fieldlab>
        <FieldVal>FPB - OK Ship Pt</FieldVal> <!-- if field order is 5, map 3rd element -->
        <FieldOrd>5</FieldOrd>
    <Info>

</Account>
<Account>
    <Action>A</Action> <!-- 3rd element in the row-->
    <org>G980</org> <!-- 2nd element-->
    <code>111FCA1GR003411XX</code> <!--concat(1st element, 4th element, 5th element)--> 
    <FiscalYear>2013</FiscalYear>
    <Info>
        <Action>A</Action> <!-- 3rd element in the row-->
        <org>G190</org> <!-- 2nd element-->
        <code>111FCA1GR003411XX</code><!--concat(1st element, 4th element, 5th element)-->
        <Fieldlab>Acc1</Fieldlab>
        <FieldVal>11FCA1GR0034</FieldVal> <!-- if field order is 1, map 1st element -->
        <FieldOrd>1</FieldOrd> 
    <Info>
    <Info>
        <Action>A</Action>
        <org>G190</org> 
        <code>111FCA1GR003411XX</code>
        <Fieldlab>Acc2</Fieldlab>
        <FieldVal>11</FieldVal>  <!-- if field order is 2, map 5th element -->
        <FieldOrd>2</FieldOrd>
    <Info>
    <Info>
        <Action>A</Action> <!-- 4th element in the row-->
        <org>G190</org> <!-- 2nd element-->
        <code>111FCA1GR003411XX</code>
        <Fieldlab>Acc3</Fieldlab>
        <FieldVal>xx</FieldVal> <!-- if field order is 3, map 6th element -->
        <FieldOrd>3</FieldOrd>
    <Info>
    <Info>
        <Action>A</Action> <!-- 4th element in the row-->
        <org>G190</org> <!-- 2nd element-->
        <code>111FCA1GR003411XX</code>
        <Fieldlab>Acc4</Fieldlab>
        <FieldVal>02</FieldVal> <!-- if field order is 4, map 7th element -->
        <FieldOrd>4</FieldOrd>
    <Info>
    <Info>
        <Action>A</Action> <!-- 4th element in the row-->
        <org>G190</org> <!-- 2nd element-->
        <code>111FCA1GR003411XX</code>
        <Fieldlab>Acc5</Fieldlab>
        <FieldVal>FPB -San Antonio</FieldVal> <!-- if field order is 5, map 3rd element -->
        <FieldOrd>5</FieldOrd>
    <Info>
</Account>
```

Could anybody help me to generate this file. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Although XSLT 2 can read non-XML input, you might find it easier to do this in a scripting language such as Python, Perl or Groovy.

Comment: If you want to avoid learning new tricks, that might be true, but the Python (etc) code is unlikely to be any simpler than the XSLT code shown below.

Comment: @MichaelKay Its not necessarily true that code in a more appropriate language will be simpler, and I don't think it is wise to suggest the use of XSLT for something (string manipulation) when the W3C says that XSLT is "a language for transforming XML documents" not generic files.

Comment: I didn't suggest the use of XSLT, the OP did. I was very happy to go along with the choice as I agree with it. The task is about reading text and writing XML, and while many languages can handle reading text, writing XML is harder to get right than many people imagine, as your example demonstrates.

Comment: My example writes invalid XML because thats what the OP asked for. Its not good, well-formed XML, but sometimes thats not what custom parsers expect.

Comment: Many thanks for all the answers. I greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this transformation in two phases (simplifies the task by breaking it down). First phase produces XML that is isomorphic to the original text; the second phase restructures the XML.

Phase 1 is something like this:

```
<xsl:template name="main">
<doc>
  <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(unparsed-text('input.txt'), '\r?\n')
                           [starts-with(., '&quot;')]">
    <row>
      <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex='\"[^"]*?\"'>
        <xsl:matching-substring>
          <col><xsl:value-of select="."/></col>
        </xsl:matching-substring>
      </xsl:analyze-string>
    </row>
  </xsl:for-each>
</doc>
</xsl:template>
```

Phase 2 is something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="doc">
  <Accounts>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </Accounts>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="row">
  <xsl:variable name="row" select="."/>
  <Account>
    <Action><xsl:value-of select="col[4]"/></Action>
    <org><xsl:value-of select="col[2]"/></org>
    <xsl:variable name="code" select="concat(col[1], col[4], col[5])"/>
    <code><xsl:value-of select="$code"/></code>
    <FiscalYear><xsl:value-of select="year-from-date(current-date())"/></FiscalYear>
    <xsl:for-each select="1 to 5">
      <xsl:variable name="p" select="."/>
      <Info>
        <Action><xsl:value-of select="$row/col[4]"/></Action>
        <org><xsl:value-of select="$row/col[2]"/></org>
        <code><xsl:value-of select="$code"/></code>
        <FieldLab>Acc<xsl:value-of select="."/></FieldLab>
        <FieldVal><xsl:value-of select="$row/col[(1,5,6,7,3)[$p]]"/></FieldVal>
        <FieldOrd><xsl:value-of select="."/></FieldOrd>
     </Info>
   </xsl:for-each>
  </Account>
</xsl:template>
```

There are various ways you can string the two phases together. You can do it within a single stylesheet (put the result of the first phase in a variable, then process it with the second phase), or you can execute them in turn from a shell script, or Ant, or XProc, or xmlsh, or a custom Java application.

Comment: The problem with this answer is that I don't think what you've made *is* more readable than the equivilent python/prel/etc... code as they are scripting languages designed for file parsing. XSLT is (or is supposed to be) about transforming XML documents. Secondly, by using XSLT the asker is now highly restricted to a Java- or CLI-based solution, which makes importing or reusing this code in a large system much more difficult.

Comment: The user asked for an XSLT 2.0 solution, and as XSLT 2.0 is highly suited to the task I was happy to supply one. Java is pretty widely available, therefore so is XSLT 2.0.

Comment: I agree that the file parsing is the key point but I don't like the idea of using multiple languages. An extended schema notation should be specified to have a declarative approach so a parser will automatically create the corresponding XDM then allow XSLT or XQuery for working with.

Comment: Well, with Rex you can certainly extend the approach to non-regular languages. For people who don't think XSLT is suitable for processing simple regular languages with regular expressions, the idea of writing an XSLT parser for a non-regular language, let alone a parser generator, probably fills them with horror. But it's do-able and it's been done.

Answer (score 0):

As the W3C states:

> [XSL Transformations (XSLT 2.0) is a language for transforming XML documents into other XML documents, text documents or HTML documents](http://www.w3.org/standards/xml/transformation)

Using XSLT in this way is more verbose and less reable, as its not designed to parse text files. While I've included a Python solution, as @JimGarrison pointed out, there are a ton of other string I/O languages that are better suited. Unless you have a strong business need that you *must* use XSLT, I'd strongly recommend looking at the code below and translating it into a language of your choice.

I think you've asked a classic [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), so I've coded up an alternative version in Python that you can see here: http://codepad.org/JWNbqrwD. It doesn't include file I/O, but thats not a terribly tricky change to add.

A few things, your output isn't XML - there is no single root element, and yout `Info` tags don't close correctly, so neither does this script.

```
import re
from datetime import datetime

data = """Directory:    sample/archive
Name:         20130613-T210002.TXT
---------------------------------------------------------------
"11FCK1GR0026" "G190" "FPB - OK Ship Pt" "A" "11" "XX" "02"
"11FCA1GR0034" "G980" "FPB -San Antonio" "A" "11" "XX" "02"
"11FCA1GR0034" "G160" "FPB -San Antonio" "A" "11" "XX" "02"
"""

output = ""

# Split on new lines start at line 3.
for line in data.split("\n")[3:]:
    fields = re.findall('"([^"]*)"',line) #Find all 
    newAccount = ""
    if len(fields) == 7:
        action, org, code = fields[3],fields[2], "".join([fields[0],fields[3],fields[4]])
        newAccount = "<Account>\n" + \
            "\t<Action>%s</Action>\n" % action + \
            "\t<org>%s</org>\n" % org + \
            "\t<code>%s</code>\n" % code + \
            "\t<FiscalYear>%s</FiscalYear>\n" % datetime.now().year
        orderMap = [(1,0),(2,4),(3,5),(4,6),(5,2)]
        for pos,fieldNum in orderMap:
            newAccount += "\t<Info>\n" + \
                "\t\t<Action>%s</Action>\n" % action + \
                "\t\t<org>%s</org>\n" % org + \
                "\t\t<code>%s</code>\n" % code + \
                "\t\t<Fieldlab>Acc%s</Fieldlab>\n" % pos + \
                "\t\t<FieldVal>%s</FieldVal>\n" % fields[fieldNum]+ \
                "\t\t<FieldOrd>%s</FieldOrd>\n" % pos + \
            "\t<Info>\n"
        newAccount += "</Account>\n"

    output += newAccount

print output
```

Comment: This code, like so many attempts to write XML from languages that weren't designed for the job, will produce ill-formed XML if the input contains special characters like & and <. It's code like this that explains why we have so many people asking on StackOverflow how to repair bad XML.

Comment: Note also, the quote from W3C is from the marketing blurb, not from the spec itself. The XSLT 1.0 spec had a similar sentence, but it was removed from the 2.0 spec as a clear signal that the capabilities of the language had increased. The marketing blurb for Java said it was for writing applets...

Comment: This is an answer, but it is not a solution. The problem here is that your answer is hard coded to the problem at hand. If one were to change the date, one will have to change the code to accommodate. An alternative solution as shown  here https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog would be a consistent output regardless if the data is changed.